# Linking to jQuery

Tags: jquery

I know this question has been asked a lot but I still can't figure out how to solve this problem. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Basically, what I did was I separated the jQuery files and added them in a template group called "styles" like so:
[image]

In the html file I tried to link them by using these code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{path="styles/java"}"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="{path="styles/cycle"}"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="{path="styles/min"}"></script>
```

I know it seems to be a dump question but I'm totally new to this.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK you can only link stylesheets up in this way. However, as was said in an answer below, it's probably better to take these out of EE's template system altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never use CSS or Javascript files as EE templates. Better to leave them as static files on the server and link to them like you normally would. Something like this (assuming the files are in a folder named "js"):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/java.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/cycle.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Benek for your quick reply. Where do I find this folder exactly? is it in the ee folder?

Comment: You have to create the folder in your web root. It's not part of the EE system. My whole point is to put those files outside of EE.

Comment: I added the folder in the web root and added the codes in the head in my html file, but it's still doesn't work. not sure what i'm doing wrong

Comment: any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Aren't the files being served or aren't the scripts working?

Comment: Hey Robson, I'm not really sure why they don't work. I made sure to add the scripts as they are in the html template. I located the "js" folder in the public_html folder. My apologies, I'm totally new to this.